# Monodevelop browser debug

Tags: mono

I started learning Asp.Net. As a test, I created my first controller that returns a string "Hello World". Now when I click on debug, I should see this string in my default browser (Firefox). Though nothing happens in my browser. All I can see is what I paste into the end of this post from the "application output" (at the right bottom of screen).

Granted, I am very new to Monodevelop and Linux also, had to change because I could no longer use my PC with Windows (the hardver was too old for it). I know Windows is the best environment to run Microsoft products, but since it is not an option for me, it would be nice if I could still use something I can work with.

Please help if you know anything I could try.

Here is what I got from the app output:

```
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll [External]
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.816213] Notice : Adding applications '/:.'...
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.872089] Notice : Registering application:
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.872225] Notice :     Host:          any
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.872325] Notice :     Port:          any
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.872420] Notice :     Virtual path:  /
[2017-09-23 22:31:25.872511] Notice :     Physical path: /home/thenakedthunder/supermva/PartyInvites/PartyInvites/
Loaded assembly: /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll [External]
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.659947] Notice : xsp4
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.699006] Notice : Listening on address: 127.0.0.1
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.699128] Notice : Root directory: /home/thenakedthunder/supermva/PartyInvites/PartyInvites
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.756700] Error  : Address already in use
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.766439] Error  :   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint localEP) [0x00043] in <c69ee271cf0840f7815cf7cea957af77>:0 
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.766560] Error  :   at Mono.WebServer.XSPWebSource.CreateSocket () [0x00014] in <ac6d9d3631224d4d8a8d381dfce3315b>:0 
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.766638] Error  :   at Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.Start (System.Boolean bgThread, System.Int32 backlog) [0x00075] in <5b4128956e344d60b82a5fd7012fd8a1>:0 
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.766714] Error  :   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:Start (bool,int)
[2017-09-23 22:31:26.766784] Error  :   at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, System.Boolean root, Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost ext_apphost, System.Boolean quiet) [0x002cd] in <ac6d9d3631224d4d8a8d381dfce3315b>:0
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This `Address already in use` is the problem, some other process is using that port on your system

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some other process is running on the default port `8080`, so you will need to change that port using the `port option` when running it:

```
xsp4 --root ~/mono --port 8081
```

or

```
xsp4 --port 8081
```

Example:

```
$ xsp4 --port 15000

xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/george/Documents/askubuntu
Listening on port: 15000 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

Info:

`~/mono`: used when running it from another location

`--port`: option to change the listening port